# How to access props of a component, that is passed as a prop itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say we have these components:

```
const Form = ({ title, inputs }) => {
   return <div>I am a form</div>
}

const Page = ({ form }) => {
   return <div>How can I access the title of the form, here?</div>
}
```

How can I access the `title` which is a prop on `Form` component, inside `Page` component?

Comment: What is `form`? is it passed as `<Page form={Form} />` or as `<Page form={<Form title="foo" inputs="bar" />} />`? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: @3limin4t0r `Form` is a function component, and it can be passed to `Page` in both forms you wrote.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Page = ({ form }) => {
   return <div>{form.props.title}</div>
}
```